# Am I allowed to shoot 3 under in World Archery's Instinctive Bow Division?

Tags: archery, legality

I'm currently thinking about switching to three under (3 fingers under the arrow knock when releasing). I ordered a new bow and wanted to take this as a chance to change or try out a few things.

However, I want my new setup to be compliant for the Instinctive Bow Division of World Archery. Am I allowed to shoot three under there?

Comment: Related https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/21982/what-would-be-the-advantage-of-the-3-fingers-under-release

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [rulebook](https://worldarchery.org/rulebook/article/3138), you can either shoot with one finger above or all below but not both.

> The bow must be shot **using the "Mediterranean" loose (one finger above the arrow nock) or fingers directly below the arrow nock (index finger no more than 2 mm below nock), with one fixed anchor point.** The athlete must choose either Mediterranean or fingers under nock, but **may not use both.** Finger protection when shooting with fingers under the nock must have a continuous surface or connected surface, with no ability to shoot split finger. When using the Mediterranean loose a separator between the fingers to prevent pinching the arrow may be used.

[Rulebook](https://worldarchery.org/rulebook/article/3138)

Comment: I'm not an archer, so this question might sound silly. But the provision that you have to choose one method sounds quite redundant to me: You are allowed to have one finger above the nock (in which case you obviously don't have all of them below), or all fingers below (in which case it is physically/logically impossible to have one above). Is this just some legalese point, or am I missing something here?

Comment: @anderas Its probably that you can use one method or the other, but you must shoot all your shots with the same method

Comment: Can someone explain to me why these rules exist? To me (ex recurve archer) this sounds very arbitrary... Why not let people lose the way they want, as long as it is a "traditional technique"? (I understand why you wouldn't want to allow the compound release triggers, ...)